# Jetpack compose app taking more than 6 sec to launch

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying jetpack compose and I build a simple app which has two fragments and those are hosted on `MainActivity`. First fragment contain a button to launch another fragment using navigation component. But the problem is when I launch the app it takes more than 6 seconds to show first fragment which is kind of weird.
So, I just want to know why it is taking more time to load. Is it because in jetpack compose there is more classes to load at runtime?

Here is my `MainActivity` code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  } }
```

Android xml file of `MainActivity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_graph"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Navigation file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/recipeListFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/recipeListFragment"
        android:name="coding.universe.recipeapp.RecipeListFragment"
        android:label="">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/launchRecipeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/recipeFragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/recipeFragment"
        android:name="coding.universe.recipeapp.RecipeFragment"
        android:label=""/>
</navigation>
```

First fragment's `onCreateView`

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Recipe List fragment")

                CustomSpacer(space = 16.dp)

                Button(onClick = { findNavController().navigate(R.id.launchRecipeFragment) },
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Go to recipe Fragment")
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Second Fragment's `onCreateView`

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
        setContent {
            Text(text = "Recipe fragment")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some possible code that someone get an idea of what you are trying to do. May be your activity code or first fragment code will help.

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ZankrutParmar I've added whole code first fragment, second fragment and Main Activity